# writeInt of DataOutputStream not working

Tags: java

I have written this program to write marks into the file called `marks.txt`, but why is the `dos.writeInt()` writing Ascii values into the file?

```
class Q5marks
{
   public static void main(String a[])throws IOException`
   {
      int marks[]=new int[6]
      File file = new File("marks.txt");
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
      {
        marks[i]=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("marks "+(i+1)+" =>" +marks[i]);
        dos.writeInt(marks[i]);
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please show us the input, as well as the actual vs desired output.

Comment: i want to insert 65 65 65 65 65 65 but it writes A A A A A A into the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with : `dos.writeBytes(marks[i]+"");` . It should work as desired by you .

Answer (score 1):

> i want to insert 65 65 65 65 65 65 but it writes A A A A A A into the file

Then you should be using [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) and not [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

Comment: why?? can you please check this example on the website? http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.io/how-to-write-file-in-java.html

Comment: @user1720452: If you tried that example, you'd see that it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It will write numerical values to the file because you've specified `writeInt`.

<strike>You may be looking to use:</strike>

```
doc.writeChar(marks[i]);
```

But I can't be too sure. Your question isn't quite clear enough.

Instead, use as PrintStream.

Comment: A   A   A   A   A   A <=this is the output for my input which is 65 65 65 65 65...

Comment: but i want to write integer value to the file not character

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking, @user1720452.

Comment: i have a file called marks.txt in which i want to insert marks which are integer but after the execution of above program the file is conating Characters not the integer

Answer (score 0):

When you call `dos.writeInt(marks[i]);` don't think that it will write the int in human readable format( as normal text editor consider all as char so your 65 become A). It will write the byte value of int. You can read the file again using the readInt() method.

EDIT:
If you want it should write the int show that you can read it with normal text editor then
use the flowing code that use a FileWriter instead of DataOutputStream. And don't forget to close the writer.

```
class Q5marks
 {
  public static void main(String a[])throws IOException
   {
  int marks[]=new int[6];
  File file = new File("marks.txt");
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
  FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(file);
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
  {
    marks[i]=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("marks "+(i+1)+" =>" +marks[i]);
    writer.write(String.valueOf(marks[i])+" ");//a space is added to increase the readability 
  }
  writer.close();
}
```

}

Comment: hi thanks now i got the explanation but can you tell me how i can write Int in human readable format?

Comment: please see the EDIT , I have given complete solutions there